# Unable to run functions in sync mode NODEJS

Tags: node.js

I am using the async module to run list of functions in sequence but only the first function named getBaseLineList gets executed. The second one does not ? I want them to run one after the other.

NodeJS

```
function getBaseLineList(){
    var data=['a','b','c'];
    console.log("Inside getBaseLineList");
    return data;
}

function getBaseLineDetails(data){
    console.log("After we get the list"+data);
}

var data =[];
async.series([
    function(callback){    
        data = getBaseLineList();   
    },
    function(callback){
        getBaseLineDetails(data);
    }
]);

app.listen(port, host);
console.log('App started on port ' + port);
```

Answer (score 1):

The functions inside `async.series` receive a `callback` argument, but you never call it. async is waiting for you to call the callback before it invokes the next function.

If `getBaseLineList` and `getBaseLineDetails` are synchronous, you can just do this:

```
var data =[];
async.series([
    function(callback){    
        data = getBaseLineList();
        callback();
    },
    function(callback){
        getBaseLineDetails(data);
        callback();
    }
]);
```

...but if they're synchronous, you shouldn't be using async anyway—you should just call one after the other.

If they're asynchronous, you'll need to pass `callback` to each one of them and have them invoke it whenever they're done. I can't really show you how to do that, though, without seeing the actual asynchronous code.

Answer (score 0):

Emmm you can use async.waterfall

```
async.waterfall([
    function(callback){    
        callback(null, getBaseLineList());
    },
    function(data, callback){
        getBaseLineDetails(data);
        callback();
    }
], function(err, result) {
    app.listen(port, host);
    console.log('App started on port ' + port);
});
```